# MySQL to PostgreSQL Migration on MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, postgresql

I want to convert my current DB to Postgres. I want not only data conversion (RazorSQL solved this problem) but also indexes migration (just creating the same one in postgres automatically) and autoincrement migration (autoincrement value from each mysql table to sequence start value in postgres tables).

I'm using MacOS and I would be happy to find solution (if it's real) for this OS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a pure conversion... I would say it is a migration.

I suggest you look at Pentaho Kettle for that, it runs also on Mac OS where I normally use it for data migration and ETL.